# Connecting to external MySQL in ruby. ERROR 1130 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

I know that there are bunch of similar topics created, however, they do not answer my issue.

I started with a simple example to connect to my already created MySQL data.
This is that I am working with:

```
require 'mysql2'

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "dbIP_addr", :username => "db_usern", :password => "db_passw", :database => "db_name")

puts client
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error:

```
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'myIP_addr' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server
```

I followed several examples and they didn't help me. "[Allow remote connections to your MySQL server](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/12/27/allow-remote-connections-to-your-mysql-server/)" is the most understandable to me.

As I still have this issue, I need your help to help me understand where the problem is.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you using MariaDB server? Check your MariaDB server configurations to allow remote connections. possible that you're connecting to a MariaDB server that blocked a remote connection

here you go https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/

Comment: It's still blocked..

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Ruby problem since the error says the server can't connect.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a 'db_usern' user that matches the source IP/dns (you should turn off PTR lookups for host auths).

Comment: That might be an answer. Could you tell more what I should look for on google?  I tried [this one](https://www.linux-tips.org/article/92/disabling-reverse-dns-lookups-in-ssh)  but not sure if this is an answer.